# Given that $a^2(a+k)=b^2(b+k)=c^2(c+k)$, find the value of $1/a+1/b+1/c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $$a^2(a+k)=b^2(b+k)=c^2(c+k)$$
>   find the value of $1/a+1/b+1/c$.

I tried to derive a relation from the equality but it did not help my cause.

Comment: Algebra portion of what?

Comment: The problem is missing a condition that $a$, $b$, $c$ are pairwise distinct.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Let $$a^2(a+k)=b^2(b+k)=c^2(c+k)=d$$

So $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3+x^2k-d=0$

Using [Vieta's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), $a+b+c=-k, ab+bc+ca=0,abc=d$

$$\text{Now,}\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}$$

Comment: ..thank you....it ws nt neccesary to mention the name vieta's formula..

Comment: @soumajitdas, welcome. But, why should we keep back the name to whom the formula is ascribed?

Comment: (minor point) we need the assumption that they are distinct.

Comment: @CalvinLin, if $x^3+kx^2-d=0$ has repeated roots,  it has some roots common with $$\frac{x^3+kx^2-d}{dx}=0\implies 3x^2+2kx=0$$  Now, $3x^2+2kx=0\implies x=-\frac{2k}3$ or $0$ If $x=-\frac{2k}3$ is the common root, we can write $a=b=-\frac{2k}3$ and as $a+b+c=-k, c=\frac k3\implies \frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=0$ if $k\ne0$. If $x=0$ is the common root, $a=b=0, c=-k$ and $\frac1a,\frac1b $ are undefined . So, the only condition we need is $abc\ne0$ and of course $k\ne0$

Comment: You're missing my point. Regardless of whether there are repeated roots, We know that $r^2(r+k) = r^2(r+k) =r^2(r+k) $, so we could have $a=b=c=r$, where $r$ is any complex (non-zero) number, and the sum is $\frac{3}{r}$. So we do need the condition that they are distinct, in order to claim that $\{a,b,c\}$ is indeed the (multi-)set of roots, which allows you to apply vieta's.

Comment: @CalvinLin, $!(a=b=c)$ does not imply $a\ne b\ne c,$ two of them may be equal, here $=-\frac{2k}3\ne0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That is why we require the assumption that they are pairwise distinct. For any pair of complex numbers $r, s$, there is some (possibly complex) value of $k$ such that $r^2(r+k)=r^2(r+k)=s^2(s+k)$.